# How to efficiently generate multiple random graphs with random edge weights in networkx

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, networkx, nested-loops

I would like to generate multiple Erdos-Renyi graphs with random edge weights. However, my code works quite slow since there are two nested loops. I was wondering if someone can help me with improving my code.

```
import networkx as nx
import random

#Suppose I generate 1000 different random graphs
for _ in range(1000):
    #Let's say I will have 100 nodes and the connection probability is 0.4
    G= nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(100,0.4)
    #Then, I assign random edge weights.
    for (u, v) in G.edges():
            G.edges[u,v]['weight'] = random.randint(15,5000)
```

When I run a similar code block in `R` using `igraph`, it is super fast regardless of the size of the network. What are some alternative ways that I can accomplish the same task without facing slow execution time?

Comment: just checking if `nx.nx.fast...` is a typo

Comment: There is unfortunately not much to do here... Networkx is slow library. Wrapping functions to transform the graph in data structure of fast libraries (like Numpy) are so slow that using them is actually completely pointless in term of performance... For example a simple transformation to a 100x100 array takes 3 ms while it could theoretically be (at least) 100x time faster! I can only advise you to use another library...

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for the great explanation. Could you tell me what libraries I can use instead of ````networkx````?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This benchmark](https://www.timlrx.com/blog/benchmark-of-popular-graph-network-packages) shows the performance of many graphs libraries (from different languages). It confirms NetworkX is very slow. The graph-tool Python package seems a significantly faster alternative to NetworkX. Please note that the performance of a given package is dependent of what you want to achieve because the performance of a graph algorithm is very dependent of the chosen internal representation.